# Importing posts with existing ID

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to import posts from an XML export. Some posts are missing its featured image, since the ID of the featured image already exists in the new system, hence creating the featured image is skipped.

Is there anything I can do about that?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing it with a tool like [WP All Import](http://www.wpallimport.com/). This plugin allows you to provide action when data already exists (like updating). If you have a proper XML this import tool should do the trick.

You should never try to import data where you forcefully want the same ID, that messes things up. So allow new ID's to be created (the plugin does this for you).